# Finding if convergent, which type, or divergent

Tags: analysis

Absolutely Convergent, Conditionally Convergent, or Divergent?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n^5+2n} - \sqrt{n^5 +1})$$

Attempt:

$x_n = (\sqrt{n^5+2n} - \sqrt{n^5 +1}) * \frac{\sqrt{n^5+2n} + \sqrt{n^5 +1}}{\sqrt{n^5+2n} + \sqrt{n^5 +1}}$

= $\frac{2n - 1}{\sqrt{n^5+2n} + \sqrt{n^5 +1}}$

= $\frac{2n - 1}{(n^5+2n)^{1/2} + (n^5 +1)^{1/2}}$

$\le$ $\frac{2n - 1}{2n^{5/2}}$

Since $\frac{2n - 1}{2n^{5/2}}$ converges via p-test, then the original series should converge as well by comparison test.

I think what I have so far make sense. Maybe. Where do I go from here. I believe it's convergent, but how would I show if it's absolutely convergent, or conditionally convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely convergent if and only if it's convergent, because the summand is positive. So assuming your arithmetic is right, that's your answer: it's absolutely convergent.

Incidentally, you can use Cauchy condensation and then the ratio test to get the same answer.

Comment: So if I use a comparison test, ratio test, etc and come to the conclusion that it converges I can just go and end my proof? If that's the case, then when would you come across something that is conditionally convergent?

Comment: "Conditionally convergent" is only possible when the summand changes sign infinitely often. The ratio test, if conclusive, proves things to be absolutely convergent straight away (no matter what the sign of the summand is); the comparison test also does, since in my statement of the comparison test it can only be used on positive summands. The alternating series test only proves convergence, not absolute convergence.

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid messages like "thank you", but nonetheless, thank you very much for your concise answer. You explained it very clearly.